# Python / Selenium How to interact with Hidden Select element

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, hidden-field

This is HTML code for the element which I need to select specific option

```
<div class="ui-dropdownlistcontrol">
<select id="ApplicantTitle" name="ApplicantTitle" class="select2-hidden-accessible" data-select2-id="ApplicantTitle" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="0" selected="" data-select2-id="2">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="1" data-select2-id="6">Mr</option>
    <option value="2" data-select2-id="7">Mrs</option>
    <option value="3" data-select2-id="8">Miss</option>
    <option value="4" data-select2-id="9">Ms</option>
    <option value="5" data-select2-id="10">Dr</option>
    <option value="6" data-select2-id="11">Prof</option>
    <option value="7" data-select2-id="12">Hon</option>
    <option value="8" data-select2-id="13">Sir</option>
    <option value="9" data-select2-id="14">Lord</option>
</select>
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="1" style="width: 100%;">
    <span class="selection">
        <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-ApplicantTitle-container">
            <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-ApplicantTitle-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true">&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation">
                <b role="presentation"></b>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="1" style="width: 100%;">
    <span class="selection">
        <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-ApplicantTitle-container">
            <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-ApplicantTitle-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true">&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation">
                <b role="presentation"></b>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
```

Select element is hidden and I can't simply do this
`.....find_elements_by_xpath('./following::select//option[text()="Mr"]')[0].click()`

And if you will select `Mr` then inside the `span` elements `&nbsp;` will be changed to the selected option

Does someone know how to interact with the hiddle `select` element?

Or any suggestion will be appreciated

**EDIT 1:**

I can press element with this id `select2-ApplicantTitle-container` then the drop down will show up, but then what is the way to select from this opened list?

Comment: You should interact with it just like a user would. Do whatever in the UI a user would do to expose the hidden SELECT. If there is no way to unhide the SELECT, then you will have to just interact with the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code ::

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='ApplicantTitle']")))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)  

select = Select(element)
select.select_by_visible_text('Mr')
```

Note:  Add below impoerts to your solution

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

You can deal with drop down with multiple ways:

1. select_by_index(index)
2. select_by_value(value)
3. select_by_visible_text(text)

** Solution 2: **

```
driver.get('https://www.santanderforintermediaries.co.uk/calculators-and-forms/affordability/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='ddlMethodRepaymentSelectBoxIt']")))
element.click()

element1= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='ddlMethodRepaymentSelectBoxItOptions']//li[4]/a")))
element1.click()
```

[image]

**Solution 3:**

```
driver.get("https://www.santanderforintermediaries.co.uk/calculators-and-forms/affordability/")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

element1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ddlMethodRepaymentSelectBoxIt")))
element1.click()

elements =  WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='ddlMethodRepaymentSelectBoxItOptions']//li[*]")))


expected_value = "Capital and interest"

for element in elements:
    if element.text == expected_value:
        element.click()
        break
```

Comment: The same as I have received before `Element <option> could not be scrolled into view`

Comment: + your link is broken ;)

Comment: The same issue, this select element is not visible, this is the problem

Comment: Can you share your url ?  Initially you were saying scrolled issue.

Comment: You can find similar behaviour here - https://www.santanderforintermediaries.co.uk/calculators-and-forms/affordability/

`Method of repayment` question

Comment: Cant find your element

Comment: Check the behaviour of this one http://prntscr.com/tpvpj0

Comment: Mate this is not a drop down box. example which you are providing is custome drop down. please check updated section  solution2 for your ref

Comment: Based on your solution, what is the way to select different option?

Comment: Just change xpath //ul[@id='ddlMethodRepaymentSelectBoxItOptions']//li[4]/a to your choice in simple words you need to change li[index]

Comment: Nope - This is the `span` element even if I press it and the list of options will appear, not sure how to get them to be selected, as they are visible on the page, but nowhere in the backend.... the only options are from select element (which is hidden and not interactible) This is a similar example - http://prntscr.com/tpw7md

Comment: Sorry every time you are giving new url so cant get to root of your issue. Please share real url

Comment: I can't share the real URL as it is not publicly accessible (unfortunately)

Comment: I have proved you 3 different working solutions. try one of them to resolve yourr issue

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the `select` list first using the below CSS and then select the item.

```
listEle = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select#ApplicantTitle")
listEle.click()
#Then you can select the option 
listEle.find_element_by_xpath("./option[.='Mr']").click()
```

Comment: Please check similar problem:
https://www.santanderforintermediaries.co.uk/calculators-and-forms/affordability/ and check this element http://prntscr.com/tpvs9x

Answer (score 0):

The UI seems as a dropdown but its not same. If there is a Select tag in HTML and not wrapped in some other tag then it can be selected using Selenium Select class.

In your reference site you need to simulate the same click action in order to select a value from dropdown.

Use below code:

```
driver.get("https://www.santanderforintermediaries.co.uk/calculators-and-forms/affordability/")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
# click on dropdown
driver.find_element_by_id("ddlMethodRepaymentSelectBoxIt").click()

#get all dropdown element
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#ddlMethodRepaymentSelectBoxItOptions>li")

expected_value = "Part and part - sale of mortgaged property"

# loop through all all element and and check whether element has the expected value to select if yes the select and break out the loop
for element in elements:
    if element.text == expected_value:
        element.click()
        break
```

Comment: How this then work with my HTML? WHen I do not have list of option in `li` element ?

Comment: You can get the exact locator of your values. HTML Shared by you seems not the same element what you intend to select

Comment: As you have mentioned while click `select2-ApplicantTitle-container` dropdown popup, Now locate that drodown popup and its values

Comment: This is the problem can't get these elements from drop-down - http://prntscr.com/tpw7md

Comment: I can't see dropdown value there in screenshot. I can see only dropdown element there not values. If you hover the inspector then it will show the value in console

Comment: This is the problem (( even in inspector can't find this options

Comment: Please share your website URL so someone could look into it without sufficient info its not possible to decide whats wrong.